# how to force svcutil use xml serialization instead runtime serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, svcutil.exe

I'm using a service reference (the xsd visual studio tool) to generate a a cs (Reference.cs) in order to serialice and deserialice some classes but I need use System.Xml.Serialization instead System.Runtime.Serialization. how can i archieve this? I've been trying with some advanced options "like reuse types in referenced assemblies" and uncheck options but nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

> /serializer:XmlSerializer
>
> Generates data types that use the XmlSerializer for serialization and
>   deserialization. Short Form: /ser:XmlSerializer